# How to put the current charts (eg. from 'Spotify Charts API') in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, spotify

I want to put a list of the current charts on my website and i want to use [**Spotify Charts API**](http://charts.spotify.com/docs) or something similar like last.fm. The problem is, that i don't know how to proceed `JSON` reponses into a `HTML` tag. I don't wan't to use `PHP` if it isn't necessary.

Edit:

I want to get the current Most-Played tracks from http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/global/daily/latest and put it in a table. The solution with Knockout.js from @Zack works fine for me, but i want to get the live charts from the link above.

Comment: So you want to display the results from this url http://charts.spotify.com/api/tracks/most_streamed/global/daily/latest in a table on a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a quick example of using Knockout.js, you can bind html elements to data that is in json format.

http://jsfiddle.net/6cnex3pg/1/

```js
function TracksViewModel() {
  this.callData = {
    "tracks": [{
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/78TTtXnFQPzwqlbtbwqN0y",
      "track_name": "FourFiveSeconds",
      "artist_name": "Rihanna"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/4rmPQGwcLQjCoFq5NrTA0D",
      "track_name": "Uptown Funk",
      "artist_name": "Mark Ronson"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/6DrBnEWZ5kxvBiBaDaGQnc",
      "track_name": "Sugar",
      "artist_name": "Maroon 5"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/34gCuhDGsG4bRPIf9bb02f",
      "track_name": "Thinking Out Loud",
      "artist_name": "Ed Sheeran"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/7y2YUIyCuVhBidENVT0068",
      "track_name": "Love Me Like You Do - From \u0022Fifty Shades Of Grey\u0022",
      "artist_name": "Ellie Goulding"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/7dS5EaCoMnN7DzlpT6aRn2",
      "track_name": "Take Me To Church",
      "artist_name": "Hozier"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/4WGyY671Z37inSpCTBJoIm",
      "track_name": "Earned It (Fifty Shades Of Grey) - From The \u0022Fifty Shades Of Grey\u0022 Soundtrack",
      "artist_name": "The Weeknd"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/6SEizXg6WimNyK8NdI9biV",
      "track_name": "Time of Our Lives",
      "artist_name": "Pitbull"
    }, {
      "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/6kwAbEjseqBob48jCus7Sz",
      "track_name": "Elastic Heart",
      "artist_name": "Sia"
    }],
    "prevDate": "2015-03-04"
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new TracksViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: callData.tracks">
  <li>
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: track_url, title: track_name }"><span data-bind="text: track_name"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now I tried to get the current charts via jquery get and getJSON but it did't work :/ can you tell me how to fetch the list live from the API?